# Do I need an index for every field when using a BinaryObject?

Tags: java, object, binary, ignite

I've been doing some experiments with Apache Ignite. I've developing a flexible object based on the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException {
Ignite start = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml");
CacheConfiguration<Integer, BinaryObject> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();
cfg.setQueryEntities(new ArrayList<QueryEntity>() {{
    QueryEntity e = new QueryEntity();
    e.setKeyType("java.lang.Integer");
    e.setValueType("BinaryTest");
    e.setFields(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(){{
        put("name", "java.lang.String");
    }});
    add(e);
}});
IgniteCache<Integer, BinaryObject> cache = start.getOrCreateCache(cfg).withKeepBinary();
BinaryObjectBuilder builder = start.binary().builder("BinaryTest");
builder.setField("name", "Test");
cache.put(1, builder.build());

QueryCursor<List<?>> query = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("select name from BinaryTest"));
System.out.println(query.getAll());
```

However I don't want to have an index on every field (I suspect this is expensive). I realise that without an index this may result in slower queries - I'm fine with this.

Using the sample code above I can not form an SQL Query without first creating an index for that field.

Is it possible to use SQL queries on BinaryObjects without indexes? (Note: I will only ever store one 'type' of binary object per cache).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes are created only when you explicitely ask for it. See [1] for details on how to configure them.

Note that SQL schema is currently static. So if you dynamically add a field to you cache data type (this is supported by binary format [2]), this field can't participate in a SQL query. To achieve that, you will need to recreate the cache with different configuration and reload the data. However, there is a ticket [3] to get rid of this limitation.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller

[3] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-735

Comment: Thanks for the answer Valentin. Is it possible to achieve the same effect by using a Map instead of a BinaryObject? Or some other type that can participate in SQL queries (but not necessarily have indexes on *all* of the fields).

Comment: You will not be able to access map elements within a SQL query.

Comment: Hang on I think we (or at least me) might have our wires crossed. Using BinaryObject I will need to define the field list via QueryEntity - I'm cool with this. However indexes will only be created for fields specified with a QueryIndex. So queries on fields without a QueryIndex entry will still *work* but will be slower (full table scan) due to no index existing. Is this correct?

Comment: Ok I went away and did some test to prove my statement above. I added 1M binary objects without an index and the SQL took 1204ms. I ran the test again with an index and the query took 65ms. In both cases the SQL worked, and the time difference proves the index has an effect.

Comment: `QueryEntity` also has `fields` property. This one lists the fields that can participate in the queries, but are not indexed. A field can't be used in a query unless you explicitly made it queryable.